# d3.js: Fade chart line when there's no data

Tags: svg, d3.js, charts

I am using d3.js to draw charts, however there are sections where there's no data and it obviously drops to zero. Like this:[image]

I was wondering if there's anyway to end the line right as the data becomes zero and then resumes when there's data again? I'm not sure how to even go about this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the line generator add this:

```
.defined(function (d) { return d.y != 0;})
```

it will prevent the line from going all the way down to the axis